# Don't Allow Duplicate Entries in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which copy paste my data in another sheet when I press the button, but it also allowing duplicate entries. I have no idea how i can stop duplicate entries to be copied.

```
Sub Register_Copy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("RACF ID")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

copySheet.Range("C4").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


copySheet.Range("B6").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

copySheet.Range("C6").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Use `.Find` to check if the data exists before copying ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout where should I use `.Find` I mean what's the syntax for that

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Comment: or copy and paste and then use [`RemoveDuplicates` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-removeduplicates-method-excel)

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be faster, if you avoid copy and pasting, but you record the value as a `String` variable and then write this string variable in column. Thus, you can also check whether the variable exists in the column before writing it.

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim newValue As Variant
    newValue = copysheet.Range("C4").Value2

    With pastesheet
        If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(newValue, .Columns(3), 0)) Then
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = newValue
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```